# Matlab reading txt formatted file

Tags: matlab

If there is a .txt file in the format

Name, Home, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3

It means the first two columns are string, and the rest are integers

How do I read first two column as vectors of strings, and another matrix as numeric values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html):

```
fileID = fopen('sometextfile.txt');
C = textscan(fileID,'%s %s %f %f %f %f %f %f','Delimiter',','); % assuming you want double data types, change as required
fclose(fileID);
celldisp(C) % C is a cell array
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this so you know exactly what's happening line by line is in the following piece of code:

```
fid = fopen('textfile.txt');
clear data

tline = fgetl(fid);
n = 1;
while ischar(tline)        
    data(n,:) = strsplit(tline(1:end),', ');
    n=n+1;
    tline = fgetl(fid);
end    

fclose(fid);

dataStrings = data(:,1:2);
dataValues = str2double(data(:,3:end));
```

where *data* contains everything in string type, *dataStrings* contains only first 2 columns as strings, and *dataValues* contains the rest of the columns as type double.

This way you get simple matrices, meaning you don't have to worry yourself with structures or cell arrays.